# How to stop Windows 7 from automatically connecting to unsecure wifi network

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

One of my neighbors has an unsecure wifi network called WLAN.  At one point in the past, I accidentally connected to it, and disconnected immediately when I noticed.  Now, when I open my laptop at home, it sometimes connects to the WLAN network first, before trying my (secured) home wifi network.

The information I've found regarding this issue seems to suggest this network should have a profile on the "Manage wireless networks" screen - *but it does not*.

How do I tell Windows 7 to never connect to networks with SSIDs called WLAN?  Or to never connect to unsecured networks without confirming with me first?

Comment: The is really no network called WLAN if you try: start, type manager wireless networks?

Comment: That is strange. It *should* show up in **Control Panel\Network and Internet\Manage Wireless Networks**.

Comment: The simple solution is to log into the remote configuration for the router ( likely the default password ) and change the settings.

Comment: No, not in Control Panel\Network and Internet\View Network Status and Tasks\Manage Wireless Networks. I even checked each network entry's properties individually in case the SSID was different than the display name for some reason.

Comment: Strange, this is not the default behavior. . .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From this [Microsoft MVP](http://theillustratednetwork.mvps.org/Netsh/Block_wireless_networks.html):

> To block a neighbor's unencrypted wireless network called **WLAN**, type this in a command window as an administrator:
>
> ```
> netsh wlan add filter permission=block ssid=WLAN networktype=infrastructure
> ```

I just had it again: after a reboot, Windows 7 automatically connected to a public open (but non-working) network I have **never** connected to, and I didn't have any option (in the UI) to prevent that. The command above (with the network name in double quotes instead of `WLAN`) completely removed the network from Windows' radar!

Answer (score 1):

There should be an option in the Manage Wireless Networks window, if not you can do one of these:

1. Delete all shown networks there
2. Disable the wireless device from Device Manager (right click on My Computer > Manage > Devices/Device Manager)
3. Uninstall the device then install it again

Answer (score 1):

Go to Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > Network and Sharing Center > Manage Wireless Networks (in the left pane) and right-click the one you want to change, then click Properties > Connection Tab.

There are three fields that can be changed: Connect automatically when in range, Connect to a more preferred network and Connect even if the network is not broadcasting. Change them accordingly.

(If you have difficulty finding the "Network and Sharing Center" you can also just click windows butten and just below "all programs" use the search bar and type it in. That's what I did)